# Como trabalhar com datas no formato dd/mm/yyyy no vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, data

Tenho uma caixa de texto nomeada de `txt_cadastro.Text`. Ao usar o seguinte comando:

```
txt_cadastro.Text = DateString
```

Meu `textbox` é preenchido no seguinte formato: `04-23-2014`
O que faço para ele ser apresentado no formato brasileiro `dd/mm/yyyy`, no caso: `23-04-2014`?

Pesquisei a respeito e vi que deveria alterar o `currentculture` para o formato certo, mas não consegui fazer isso!

Usando o seguinte comando: `txt_cadastro.Text = Format(DateString, "dd/MM/yyyy")`  a caixa de texto é preenchida com dd/MM/yyyy ao invés de 23-04-2014

Alguma sugestão mais simples de formatação de data?

Comment: O problema é em VB ou VB.Net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a idéia é mostrar a data de hoje, tenta assim:

```
txt_cadastro.Text = CDate(Now).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Ai quebrou tudo!
Escrevi exatamente do jeito que vc disse:
 'txt_cadastro.Text =CDate(DateString).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        txt_nascimento.Text = "08/10/1989"'
Não funcionou e a outra caixa deixou de ser preenchida!

Comment: Como vc está preenchendo o DateString?

Comment: Coloquei exatamente como disse... deveria substituir o DateString por outra coisa??

Comment: editei a resposta. Eu imaginei que DateString já estava com valor

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeee  estou pulando de alegria aqui. Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Embora a solução aceita irá funcionar, a abordagem de conversão em formato literal engessará a aplicação caso seja necessário no futuro tornar a apresentação mais flexível (conforme preferência do usuário).

Além disso, a depender do tamanho da aplicação, poderá gerar considerável código *boilerplate* e repetitivo (para fazer valer para todos os casos).

---

O mais correto seria utilizar a cultura do usuário corrente, conforme citado na pergunta. 
Ou então pelo menos forçá-la para usar a cultura necessária.

No caso de forçá-la, Ficaria assim:

```
' Na inicialização da sua aplicação, force a cultura padrão conforme necessidade 
' (neste caso, Português/Brasil)
Dim culturaPtBr = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR")
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culturaPtBr
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culturaPtBr

' Na apresentação de valores em tela
' Converte a data para o formato "curto", que na cultura Português (Brasil) é: dd/mm/aaaa
minhaData.ToString("d")
```

Answer (score 0):

txt_cadastro.Text = today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")